# Select only the "most complete" record

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to solve the following problem.

Let's suppose I have a table with 4 fields called a, b, c, d.

I have the following records:

```
-------------------------------------
   a   |    b    |    c    |    d  
-------------------------------------
   1   |    2    |         |             row 1 
   1   |    2    |    3    |    4        row 2 
   1   |    2    |         |    4        row 3
   1   |    2    |    3    |             row 4
```

As it's possible to observe, rows 1,3,4 are "sub-records" of row 2.

What I would like to do is, to extract only 2nd row.

Could you help me please?

Thanks in advance for the answer

EDIT: I need to be more specific.

I could have also the cases:

```
-------------------------------------
   a   |    b    |    c    |    d  
-------------------------------------
   1   |    2    |         |             row 1 
   1   |    2    |         |    4        row 2 
   1   |         |         |    4        row 3
```

where I need to extract the 2nd row,

```
-------------------------------------
   a   |    b    |    c    |    d  
-------------------------------------
   1   |    2    |         |             row 1 
   1   |    2    |    3    |             row 2 
   1   |         |    3    |             row 3
```

and again I need to extract the 2nd row.

Same for couples,

---

```
   a   |    b    |    c    |    d  
-------------------------------------
   1   |         |         |             row 1 
   1   |         |    3    |             row 2 
       |         |    3    |             row 3
```

and so on for the other examples.

(Of course, it's now always 2nd row)

Comment: what if there is more than 1 row with same sub-records?

Comment: this case shouldn't be contemplated, however I still need only the most complete record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a NOT EXISTS the records that have a better duplicate can be filtered out.

> ```
> create table abcd (
>  a int,
>  b int,
>  c int,
>  d int
> );
> ```

> ```
> insert into abcd (a, b, c, d) values
>  (1, 2, null, null)
> ,(1, 2, 3, 4)
> ,(1, 2, null, 4)
> ,(1, 2, 3, null)
>
> ,(2, 3, null,null)
> ,(2, 3, null, 5)
> ,(2, null, null, 5) 
>
> ,(3, null, null, null)
> ,(3, null, 5, null)
> ,(null, null, 5, null)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT *  
> FROM abcd AS t 
> WHERE NOT EXISTS 
> (
>    select 1
>    from abcd as d  
>    where (t.a is null or d.a = t.a)
>      and (t.b is null or d.b = t.b)
>      and (t.c is null or d.c = t.c)
>      and (t.d is null or d.d = t.d)
>      and (case when t.a is null then 0 else 1 end +
>           case when t.b is null then 0 else 1 end +
>           case when t.c is null then 0 else 1 end +
>           case when t.d is null then 0 else 1 end) < 
>          (case when d.a is null then 0 else 1 end +
>           case when d.b is null then 0 else 1 end +
>           case when d.c is null then 0 else 1 end +
>           case when d.d is null then 0 else 1 end)
> );
> ```
>
> ```
>  a |    b |    c |    d
> -: | ---: | ---: | ---:
>  1 |    2 |    3 |    4
>  2 |    3 | null |    5
>  3 | null |    5 | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=5fc66782c0dca45a3f2e0e599f250692)*

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for! I have only added a select distinct over a,b,c,d instead of select * and it worked perfectly! Thank you

Comment: @M.Orlandi Thx for the rep. Just a warning though. This won't filter out special cases like the tupples `(4, null, 6, null), (4, 5, null, null), (4, 6, null, null)`. But the nice thing about this method is that you can select the "lesses" dups by simply removing the NOT. For example if you want to delete the less complete dups.

Answer (score 0):

Most complete rows, by your definition, are the ones with the least null columns:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
WHERE (
    (CASE WHEN a IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) + 
    (CASE WHEN b IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) + 
    (CASE WHEN c IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) + 
    (CASE WHEN d IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
) =
(SELECT MAX(
    (CASE WHEN a IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) + 
    (CASE WHEN b IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) + 
    (CASE WHEN c IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) + 
    (CASE WHEN d IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)) 
FROM tablename)
```

Comment: Or more simply, since you're checking all columns: `WHERE NOT tablename IS NULL`

Comment: @eurotrash What is this? Is this a valid statement?

Comment: @forpas Yes, assuming the table name is `tablename`, by saying `NOT tablename IS NULL` it checks the whole row, and the statement will return TRUE only if none of the fields are NULL. So it's a shorter way than specifying every field.

Comment: @eurotrash have you got any documentation about it?

Comment: @forpas See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html, specifically "If the expression is row-valued, then IS NULL is true when the row expression itself is null or when all the row's fields are null"

Comment: @eurotrash there is no mention or example in the link you posted about the statement you proposed. Everything is about expressions.

Comment: @forpas `SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE NOT tablename IS NULL` accomplishes what you wrote in your original answer. I use it frequently to get rows or objects where all fields are not NULL. If you're saying my initial comment was not a full valid statement, I think it's pretty obvious that it's only addressing the part of the statement from `WHERE` onwards...

Comment: @eurotrash I'm only saying that I have never seen this kind of statement. If you can post any documentation about it or any web page mentioning it I will be glad that I learnt something today.

Comment: It's in that link. "If the expression is row-valued" - i.e. if what's being compared is a row - "then IS NULL is true when ... all the row's fields are null". So you can get NULL rows by checking that `*row* IS NULL`. You use the table/view name to get the row as a whole, so `tablename IS NULL`. To check that none of the fields are NULL, "IS NOT NULL is true when ... all the row's fields are non-null". So it should be `tablename IS NOT NULL` actually, `NOT tablename IS NULL` is TRUE when the whole row is NOT NULL, hence even if a single field is NOT NULL.

Comment: @eurotrash I tested it and it works. It's new to me and I'm glad I learned something new. So thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . I think you can use `not exists`:

```
with t as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (order by a) as id
      from t
     )
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where ((t2.a is not distinct from t.a or t2.a is not null and t.a is null) and
                         (t2.b is not distinct from  t.b or t2.b is not null and t.b is null) and
                         (t2.c is not distinct from  t.c or t2.c is not null and t.c is null) and
                         (t2.d is not distinct from  t.d or t2.d is not null and t.d is null)
                        ) and
                        t2.id <> t.id
                 );
```

The logic is that no more specific row exists, where the values match

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=4e1f028b97608396232f221549d45682) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! i have edited my question to be more specific because this is only a pattern that can happen

Comment: @M.Orlandi . . . The additional clarifications in the question helped me refine the logic.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to compute a "completion index" for each row.  In the example you provided, you might use something along the lines of:

```
   (CASE WHEN a IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1) +
   (CASE WHEN b IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1) +
   (CASE WHEN c IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1) +
   (CASE WHEN d IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1) AS CompletionIndex
```

Then SELECT the top 1 ordered by CompletionIndex in descending order.

This is obviously not very scalable across a large number of columns.  But if you have a large number of sparsely populated columns you might consider a row-based rather than column-based structure for your data.  That design would make it much easier to count the number of non-NULL values for each entity.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Gordon Linoff, we do have to use something like not exists too,

**Edit** Using EXCEPT helps

This might work...

```
SELECT * from table1 
EXCEPT
(
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table1 t2
ON  COALESCE(t1.a, t2.a, -1) = COALESCE(t2.a, -1)
AND COALESCE(t1.b, t2.b, -1) = COALESCE(t2.b, -1)
AND COALESCE(t1.c, t2.c, -1) = COALESCE(t2.c, -1)
AND COALESCE(t1.d, t2.d, -1) = COALESCE(t2.d, -1)
)
```

Here, t1 is every subset row.

Note: We are assuming value -1 as sentinel value and it does not occur in any column.